# Existence of Hadamard matrix of size NxN

Tags: algorithm, math, matrix

You are given an integer N with N <=100. Is there a Hadamard matrix of size NxN, such that:

- Each element of the matrix is either 1 or -1.
- The sum of products of corresponding elements of any two rows is zero i.e. for any a <= N and b <= N  M[a][1]*M[b][1] + M[a][2]*M[b][2]...M[a][n]*M[b][n] = 0 (considering 1 based indexing).

---

**What I have done:**

I have tried a brute force solution. Each element can either be 1 or -1. So there can be at most 2<sup>(n<sup>2</sup>)</sup> matrices. I tried checking all of these matrices but the algorithm is way too slow. O(n<sup>2</sup> * (2<sup>(n<sup>2</sup>)</sup>) actually. My computer did not show any output for n = 5 and I had to terminate the program.

Can anybody suggest a better way to solve this problem?

**Edit:** You have to not only answer Yes or No but enumerate one such matrix too. Obviously when N is odd the answer is not possible. N = 1 is a trivial case with answer as 1 or -1.

Comment: Pretty sure that `N` will have to be even...

Comment: Actually, I think that the answer is "*Yes, If and Only If N is even.*"

Comment: Yes I figured that out too. N = 1 is a trivial case with ans as -1 or 1. But even if we don't count odd N's my algorithm is still way too costly

Comment: @RBarryYoung You have to enumerate the matrix too.

Comment: Consider this: let A be such a matrix, what is the result of A * A^T (A transposed), it should be N * I   (N times matrix with 1 on the diagonal and 0 everywhere else).  That's as far I've gotten now.

Comment: Do you have to enumerate all such matrices or only one example?

Comment: @PiotrJaszkowski Why A*A^T should be N * I ?
Here is a an example for N = 2.
1 1 1 -1. 
A * A^T is 2 0 0 2  = 2 * I but 2 isn't a square

Comment: @RBarryYoung only one such example

Comment: I've edited my comment, as I noticed that N doesn't need to be square. Another thing, you can flip (change sign) entire columns without changing the property, it means that you can assume that one row consists entirely of 1's, then rest of rows should have n/2 1's.

Comment: It means that there's not such a matrix for N=6. First row of 1's, second row of 3 1's and 3 -1's. There's no third row that will have 3 1's and 3 -1's and have 3 distinct values from the second row, as one different placement gives 2 distinct values. (Don't know how to say it more clearly).

Comment: I'm getting you. I have manually solved for N = 6. And you are right about having one row consisting entirely of ones and the next row consisting of  n/2 1's and n/2 -1's. As far as I have got this means n/2 must be even or n must be a multiple of 4.(except for n = 1 and 2)

Comment: There's generic solution for N = 2^k, let A be solution for N=2^{k-1} then a solution for N is First row: |AA|, second row: |A -A|. You create a big matrix out of 4 smaller matrices. All we need now is a proof that for N not a power of 2 it is not possible to create such a matrix. Basically that's a solution for N=2k if you have one for k.

Comment: Does the problem at hand occur in the context of graph theory? I am wondering whether taking a lazy approach a.k.a. literature search could be fruitful, but without additional context it is not clear what one would search for.

Comment: @PiotrJaszkowski good job so far. But are you sure about the new matrix construction? Did you make sure that any row from |A A| is orthogonal to any row from |A -A|? EDIT: yes, I realize it :)

Comment: Yes. Let's consider two rows a and b of length k from A. Now we have 4 rows, aa, a-a, bb, b-b, a and b have k/2 different values. aa and a-a obviously have k different values, aa and bb too, aa and b-b have too as a and -b also have k/2 different values.

Comment: Yes i already realized it and edited my comment :). Now we can conclude that the solution for N=4 is (1 1 1 1), (1 -1 1 -1), (1 1 -1 -1), (1 -1 -1 1)

Comment: The kind of matrix examined here (entries all -1 or +1, rows orthogonal) is called a **Hadamard matrix**. That should help with a literature search. Wikipedia says the order of a Hadamard matrix must be 1, 2, or 4*n.

Comment: @njuffa: That's cheating :(

Comment: Sorry, (software) engineering type here. No need to prove things from scratch if proven solutions already exist :-)

Comment: We will now try to prove Hadamard's conjecture :p

Comment: Ok anyway, on wiki page provided by @njuffa there's something about algorithm for finding such a matrix for N=92, you might look into that. (saying that just in case if you missed it). Anyway, rest of the problem doesn't seem to be easy, but it was fun to get this far. Good night.

Comment: Does linking to http://neilsloane.com/hadamard/ count as enumeration?

Answer (score 2):

As the comments have pointed out, a matrix with the described properties is called a *Haramard matrix*. On these [Wikipedia writes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_matrix):

> The order of a Hadamard matrix must be 1, 2, or a multiple of 4.
>
> […]
>
> The **Hadamard conjecture** proposes that a Hadamard matrix of order 4*k* exists for every positive integer *k*
>
> […]
>
> As of 2008, there are 13 multiples of 4 less than or equal to 2000 for which no Hadamard matrix of that order is known.<sup>[[8](https://dx.doi.org/10.1007%2Fs00493-008-2384-z)]</sup> They are: 668, 716, 892, 1004, 1132, 1244, 1388, 1436, 1676, 1772, 1916, 1948, and 1964.

Since your question says *N* ≤ 100, the algorithm to decide whether such a matrix exists is easy: test for `N==1 || N==2 || (N%4)==0`.

Of course, that doesn't tell you how to generate such a matrix. Reading more Wikipedia suggests that you could combine [Sylvester's construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_matrix#Sylvester.27s_construction) for *N* = 2<sup>*k*</sup>, [Payley's construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paley_construction) for *N* = *q* + 1 where *q* = *p*<sup>*k*</sup> for some prime *p* and *q* ≡ 3 (mod 4) (ensuring *N* is a multiple of 4).

In the range *N* ≤ 100, the only *N* for which neither of these algorithms works would be *N* = 92. So you either also add [Williamson's construction](https://dx.doi.org/10.1215%2FS0012-7094-44-01108-7) or hard-code a matrix for this specific case.

[Searching](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=williamson+paley+sylvester) for the names of the construction methods I found [Eric Tressler's *Survey of the Hardamard Conjecture*](https://theses.lib.vt.edu/theses/available/etd-05042004-120929/unrestricted/thesis_revised.pdf) which describes the construction algorithms, and also contains a table decomposing numbers for Sylvester's or Payley's construction as far as possible. Comments also mention [Sloane's *Library of Hadamard Matrices*](http://www.neilsloane.com/hadamard/index.html) which has links to the actual matrices obtained by the different methods. You can use this as a source for the *N* = 92 case if you want to hard-code that.